# Suggestion: move the default textbox text out of the boxes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I find it is less intuitive having to delete the text that already exists in the textboxes (eg Title, Tags), especially when the search bar works a different way.

My suggestion is to move the instructions on filling out the forms into the line above, eg: Tags - remember to include one of (bug discussion support feature-request)

Or an alternative could be to have the textbox default text disappear and transform the text into a new space with javascript - eg it would make the page a little longer, and then the instructions move to the line below, and then when you click off the textbox it will return if you haven't written anything.

Alternative solutions and arguments are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be overthinking this a bit.

You don't actually have to delete the text. Just start typing.. try it.

Comment: I understand, it just doesn't feel intuitive and therefore I thought I might as well suggest an improvement. No cost to write a suggestion :)